# How to create field instance using loop

Tags: php

I have list of column which i am iterating in loop,How can i get all Field:inst while using this loop,as i want to replace these instances with dynamic ones.

```
     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($columns); $i++){

          $str .=  Field::inst( "'.$columns[$i].'" );
     }


     Editor::inst( $db, 'datatables_demo' )
            ->fields(

                Field::inst( 'first_name' ),
                Field::inst( 'last_name' ),
                Field::inst( 'position' ),
                Field::inst( 'email' ),
                Field::inst( 'office' ),
                Field::inst( 'extn' ),
                Field::inst( 'age' ),
                Field::inst( 'salary' ),
                Field::inst( 'start_date' )

            )
            ->process( $_POST )
            ->json();
```

Like this is what i want

```
     Field::inst( 'first_name' ) to
     Field::inst( $column[$i] )
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `Editor::fields()` method?

Comment: What you have there is not OOP. It's just procedural code, that you have wrapped in static classes.

Comment: Can we still get the desire result,and sorry for the bad tag @tereško